# DynamoDB search

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am working on an application, in which it is required to provide a search on the data in DynamoDB. To be more clear lets say a user type "order" in search box, then it is required to check on "Pk","sk","columns" list of map (columns -> Column_Name) , "custom_table_description" and "default_table_description" , if any of the above fields have "order" then that specific documents is required to show. Can any one help/guide me if I can wrire query to search on list of map field(Like columns) ??

DynamoDB data is shown below :

```
{
"PK": "table#*****",
"SK": "schema#*****",
"classification": "Sales",
"Columns": [
{
"Column_ID": "1",
"Column_Name": "orderId",
"Custom_Column_Desc": ""
},
{"Multiple Maps"}  
],
"Custom_Table_Description": "",
"Data_classification": "Class 3",
"Data_Refresh_Rate": "24",
"Date_Pattern": "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS",
"Default_Table_Description": "some description here",
"max_date": "",
"min_date": "",
"Primary_Key": [
"DOC_TYPE",
"COMP_FA",
"LOC_CD"
],
"S3_Layer": "*****",
"S3_Location": "s3://bucket-name/folder/folder/",
"Source_Description": "***",
"Source_Vendor": "***",
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't search DDB like you can an RDBMS or OpenSearch (Elasticsearch) for instance.

I'd highly recommend going through the various AWS presentations on YouTube...

In particular here's a link to [The Iron Triangle of Purpose - PIE Theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwnNbLXN4vA&t=2530s)  chapter of the ***AWS re:Invent 2018: Building with AWS Databases: Match Your Workload to the Right Database (DAT301)*** presentation.
[image]

DynamoDB provides IE - Infinite Scale and Efficiency.

But you need P - Pattern Flexibility.

You'll need to decide if you need PI or PE.